# How can I count the amount of trues and falses in an 2d boolean array?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, double

I have a boolean array set up and I need to find out how many trues and falses it stores...

```
    boolean[][] SignalMap = new boolean[Size][Size];
```

How would I go about doing this?

```
    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
{
    int counter = 0;
            if(SignalMap = true)
            counter++;
    {
    System.out.println("true: " + counter)
    System.out.println("flase: " + (Size - counter));
```

Comment: This looks more like an 2d array of doubles than an array of booleans...?

Comment: It stores 0 trues and 0 falses because that array does not store booleans.

Comment: You declare 2 `int` variables and initialize them to zero.  Then you will need two nested loops.  Inside the inner loop you put an `if-else` statement that will check the value of array element and increment the appropriate counter.

Comment: @PM77-1 That is the correct answer for this question, I hope no one just gives the code without seeing the OP's attempted solution

Comment: @PM77-1 - Actually, you only need one counter, in addition to the array index counters.  The number of falses is the total number of entries minus the number of trues.

Answer (score 3):

Want to see a one-line solution?

```
int trueCount = Arrays.deepToString(SignalMap).replaceAll("[^t]", "").length();
```

The false count is of course the compliment:

```
int falseCount = Size * Size - trueCount;
```

Comment: I love one-line solutions! ;)

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation

First of all, you initialized `counter` to be equal to 0 each iteration of the `for loop`, which will reset it every time. That's not what you want; do it once at the top (*before* the `for loop`).

Secondly, you need to have a *nested* `for loop` to iterate through every column in every row and then count the number of "trues" like that.

Thirdly, your comparing statement `if(SignalMap = true)` isn't correct because:

1. you're dealing with a 2D array, so you need to specify positions in the matrix. so `SignalMap` would have to be `SignalMap[rowPosition][columnPosition]`
2. `SignalMap = true` is setting it equal to `true`, which you can't do. You want to compare it to see *if it is* `true`, so you should write `SignalMap == true`.

Finally, the number of false `booleans` stored will be the number of `true booleans` subtracted from the row size multipied by the column size. This is because there are `rowSize` number of columns, and in each column, there are `colSize` `booleans`. So multiply them to get the total number of booleans in the 2D array.

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

#### Code

```
boolean[][] SignalMap = new boolean[rowSize][colSize];
int counter = 0; // initialize before the for loops

for(int r = 0; r < rowSize; r++) { // loop for rows
   for (int c = 0; c < colSize; c++) { // nested loop for columns
      if (SignalMap[r][c]) // if array boolean at r and c position is true...
          counter++; // add one to the counter
   }
}

System.out.println("true: " + counter)
System.out.println("false: " + (rowSize * colSize - counter));
// total number of booleans in array is rowSize * colSize
// and total # of false booleans is total # of booleans - # of true booleans
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(SignalMap[i] == true) // this is for a regular array
```

This may be what you want for a 2D array

```
 for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < Size; j++) {
          if(SignalMap[i][j])  // will result to true if SignalMap[i][j] is in fact true
              counter++;
      }
 }
```

Comment: That is an anti pattern. Prefer `if (boolVar)` to `if (boolVar == true)` due to risk of assignment bug `if (boolVar = true)`

Answer (score 0):

Since this is Java, your variables should be lower case.

```
boolean[][] signalMap = new boolean[size][size];
```

For each dimension of your array, you need a for loop.

Here's one way to code the double for loop.  The counter needs to be initialized outside the for loops.

```
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (signalMap[i][j]) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("true: " + counter);
        System.out.println("false: " + (size * size - counter));
```